# Rename directory names and class names of maagento php files

Tags: php, magento

I am a newbie to php and the modification that I have to do also very simple.

I have a php code of magento, in this code all I need to rename one folders and some class names, and it shouldn't affect any functionality of the code after doing this small modification.

**Folders names need to change:**

I have a folder structure like:

```
\app\code\community\somename1\somename2\controllers\subfolder etc..
```

So, what happens when I change the folder names of `"somename1"` and `"somename2"`, will it affect functionality of code? I am guessing it will.

**Class Names need to change:**

I have some class names like:

`class SomeName1_Somename2_SomeController`

So I need to rename (or) delete `Somename1_somename2`, ultimately functionality of code shouldn't be affected

I have "Jetbrains Php Storm" IDE, I added code in it and  tried to modify folders/class names but its not showing me any errors. And I am not sure whether it affects the functionality either.

So, can anyone please tell me how to achieve my small task?

**Edited"**
Basically I am a Java person and I use eclipse IDE.. In eclipse, if I change any folder name or change some class name, it automatically gets replaced everywhere in the project, so is that possible such thing to achieve using PhpStorm IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Magento's autoloader uses class names to determine the path to class files, e.g. `Company_Module_Helper_Data` must reside in the `Company/Module/Helper/Data.php` file for it to be properly loaded.

So if you change the names of any folders, be sure to change the names of all the classes correspondingly.

Comment: Basically I am a Java person and I use eclipse IDE.. In eclipse, if I change any folder name or change some class name, it automatically gets replaced everywhere in the project, so is that possible such thing with PhpStorm IDE?

Comment: Not that I know of. The naming convention is pretty Magento-specific, so I doubt there's widespread IDE support for renaming classes based on changes to the file structure. You can try the [Magicento](http://magicento.com/) plugin for PHPStorm; it might do that.

Comment: hey, I just downloaded that plugin, can you please tell me how do I rename every folder, file perfectly without missing my functionality?